# Error using MySQL Connector/Python with Django 1.11

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector

I have created Django project through the following command from cmd:

```
django-admin.py startproject database
```

then I edit settings.py as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME' : 'music',
        'USER':'python',
        'PASSWORD':'123654789',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.2',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'automatic':True,
        }
    }
 }
```

When I run `python manage.py shell` or `python manage.py runserver` 
I got error

```
type Error None type object is not callable
```

I am using:

```
Python version 3.4.3,
Os win8,
Django version 1.11,
mysql 5.7,
MySQL Connector/Python.
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Ghimire\djcode\database\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 336, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL Connector/Python does not always support the latest version of Django. Your traceback looks similar to [this issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86105).

I suggest you try using `mysqlclient` instead, which is the [recommended choice for using MySQL with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers).

Comment: i am tired of trying to installing mysqlclient(also recomended on django tutorial) whith following versions: python3.4 win8 and mysql5.7, dear sir please give me some suggestions on this .

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with installing mysqlclient on Windows. You might have more luck with Python 3.5 or Python 3.6 because there are wheels available. Alternatively, you try an earlier version of Django which works with MySQL Connector/Python (Django 1.8 LTS and 1.10 are both supported for now), or use a different database backend e.g. sqlite.

Comment: i have downloaded python3.6 should i remove my older python3.4 
. if not then for which version of python the package will be installed using pip install package.

Comment: You can have Python 3.4 and 3.6 installed alongside each other on Windows. Which version `pip` uses depends on your path. I can't help with that because I'm not familiar with Windows, and it's getting off topic for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patched version of the mysql connector at https://github.com/multiplay/mysql-connector-python for Django 1.11 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

in your database settings replace:

```
'ENGINE':'mysql.connector.django',
```

with:

```
'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql'
```

Comment: Remember to install `mysqlclient` when you change the database engine!

Comment: i am tired of trying to install MySQLdb and mysqlclient. when i tried pip install mysqlclient always ends with error: cannot open include file myconfig.h . and i have followed too much instruction on internet and i found the best solution is to use mysql connector to access mysql database and worked fine. Its not working only on django. if you have any complete solution please inform me. i have win8(64 bit),python3.4.3, django 1.11 and pyconnector.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was using exact same configuration. So. First I was trying mysqlclient but it didn't work so I installed mysql-connector==2.1.6 and surprisingly it was also not working with Django1.11 so I did some research on google and found the solution.

If >>> 
you are facebook user login and visit https://www.facebook.com/groups/python.django/permalink/1657026527681920/

Else >>>

1) activate your virtualenv.

2) pip3 install mysql-connector==2.1.6

3) visit: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/tree/master/lib/mysql/connector/django ...and download base.py for django1.11.

4) Now, go to your env's lib/python(version)/site-packages/mysql/connector/django and replace base.py with downloaded base.py downloaded previously.